# VBA pivot filter on variable date

Tags: vba, variables, filter, pivot

I'm really struggling with coding pivot tables in VBA. I just want to filter on a variable date. With 1 pivot it works fine, with the other pivot - which uses the same data - I always get the same error messages:

> unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Here is my code:

```
str_Date_To_Show = Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")

'Pivot1

Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = str_Date_To_Show

'Pivot3
Sheets("Pivot3").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Pivot3").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
Sheets("Pivot3").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = str_Date_To_Show
```

I also tried this for Pivot3. It works when I hard-code the date in VBA but then I don't manage to make `2017-09-01` a variable.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("[Range].[Date].[Date]"). _
    VisibleItemsList = Array("[Range].[Date].&[2017-09-01T00:00:00]")
```

Comment: What is the declaration for `str_Date_To_Show`, is it as `Date`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Good point but changing it to 'Date' doesn't help. Even the first line for Pivot3 already bugs, for that line the declaration can't have an impact.

Comment: I mean, that's a question, how do you declare the `str_Date_To_Show` variable?

Comment: it was declared as String. I now tested it as Date as well. No success.